# How do I trigger a jQuery 'on' event with a data parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I am trying to trigger my event:

`$('table#budget').on('change', '.dyn-employee', function() {});`

at the end of a different event in my code.

```
$('table#budget').on('click', '.addButton', function() {
    // ..more code

    $('table#budget').trigger('change');
});
```

However, this does not work. I've tried using:

`$('table#budget').trigger('change', 'dyn-employee');
$('table#budget').trigger('change', ['dyn-employee']);`

but these do not work. I can't seem to find anything in the jQuery documentation either. The code is also in chronological order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is delegated, so the handler will only fire when the target is a `.dyn-employee`, so you should trigger on a specific `.dyn-employee`

```
$('#budget .dyn-employee').trigger('change');
```